# Remove duplicate items from Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I had problem during importing products. And now some of the products are duplicated. All of the duplicated products have the same title and attribute (collection_id). Also there are a lot of duplicated media files. Is there a way to remove duplicated products? At least i want to remove products.

Comment: have you tried "Fix Duplicates" plugin. that had helped me years ago.

Comment: i have tried it, thank you it is realy helpfull. But how can i delete duplicated images from server? They named like - imagename.jpg and imagename-2.jpg

Comment: you can use Media Deduper plugin to index and find duplicated image

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was I did.

1.- In my database found duplicated products (searching by sku) with the query:

```
SELECT meta_value, count(*) AS total FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' GROUP BY meta_value HAVING total > 1
```

2.- I create a new table called wp_repeated with these skus:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_repeated AS SELECT meta_value, count(*) AS total FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' GROUP BY meta_value HAVING total > 1
```

3.- I got the post_id from these skus:

```
SELECT p.ID FROM `wp_posts` as p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as m on p.ID = m.post_id WHERE p.post_type IN ('product','product_variation') AND m.meta_key = '_sku' AND m.meta_value in (select meta_value from wp_repeated)
```

4.- And, finally, remove and delete from all tables where the post_id appears:

```
DELETE relations.*, taxes.*, terms.* FROM wp_term_relationships AS relations INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS taxes ON relations.term_taxonomy_id=taxes.term_taxonomy_id INNER JOIN wp_terms AS terms ON taxes.term_id=terms.term_id WHERE object_id IN (SELECT p.ID FROM `wp_posts` as p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as m on p.ID = m.post_id WHERE p.post_type IN ('product','product_variation') AND m.meta_key = '_sku' AND m.meta_value in (select meta_value from wp_repeated)); DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN ( SELECT p.ID FROM `wp_posts` as p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as m on p.ID = m.post_id WHERE p.post_type IN ('product','product_variation') AND m.meta_key = '_sku' AND m.meta_value in (select meta_value from wp_repeated)); DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN (SELECT p.ID FROM `wp_posts` as p INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as m on p.ID = m.post_id WHERE p.post_type IN ('product','product_variation') AND m.meta_key = '_sku' AND m.meta_value in (select meta_value from wp_repeated));
```

I hope it can be helpful to you. Regards.

**TAKE CARE**: these queries remove ALL repeated products.